# ViewHelper layer in ASP.NET Web application project design

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a ASP.NET application.I have designed the application to have few libraries and a web application project. I have designed a ViewHelper layer, which will provide a View class consist of few user controls. Now, as my User Controls resides in the ASP.NET Web application project I cannot load them in some other layer.

```
ViewHelper class Library code:

public class MainView
{
   UserControl uc1;
}

MainView GetView()
{
   EmployeeView view = (EmployeeView)page.LoadControl(@"\WebControls\EmployeeView.ascx");

   MainView view = new MainView ();
   view.uc1 = view 

 }
```

The above code, I have tried to decorate my View with a User Control. But the EmployeeView  user control resides in the Web Application layer.So, it is not available in the ViewHelper layer. As a workaround I am planning to have View classes and factory in a folder in the Web application layer itself. But it is not a good practice to have class files in Web Application layer. Is there any better way for doing this?

Comment: Why do this? Why not just write an MVC application?

Comment: Why you "cannot load them in some other layer"? Why "it is not a good practice to have class files in web app layer"?

Comment: It's not a good practice in late 2014 to mess up with Web Forms.

Comment: I cannot load then in other class lib layer as it is in the Web Application projects which has aspx and ascx files.

Comment: You can have base classes declared in separate libraries and user controls to be just placeholders.